# Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent identically distributed variables each having exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent identically distributed variables each having exponential distribution with parameter $1$. Find the limiting distribution of $\frac {n} {X_1^{-1}+...+X_n^{-1}}$.

It's hard to solve it with characteristic functions directly, so I want to use the theorem that if  $X_n  \to X$ in distribution and $Y_n \to C $in probability, then $X_nY_n \to XY$ in distribution, but I fail to find the appropriate $X_n$ and $Y_n$.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_n=X_n^{-1}$. Then $(Y_n)$ is i.i.d. and $EY_1=\infty$. SLLN shows that $\frac 1n (Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n ) \to \infty$ almost surely. (SLLN is usually stated with the assumption that that mean is finite but the result holds for non-negative r.v.'s with infinite mean). It follows now that the given sequence converges to $0$ almost surely.

[By the usual SLLN we have $\frac 1n (Y_1\wedge N+Y_2\wedge N+...+Y_n\wedge N ) \to E(Y_1 \wedge N)$ and $E(Y_1 \wedge N) \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$].